# Why does the JPEG RLE diagonalize?

Tags: jpeg

The JPEG JFIF format run length encodes the 8x8 blocks in diagonal order.

Why is this better than straightforward rasterization, Hilbert curve or Z-curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG encodes blocks of DCT coefficients in zig-zag order to work from low to high frequencies in both X and Y simultaneously. If you were to traverse the block in rows or columns, you would step from low to high frequencies over and over. JPEG achieves most of its compression by removing the high frequency A/C coefficients through quantization. By doing it in a zig-zag order, it will get the best compression of the (now sequential) high frequency coefficients using a run-length encoding scheme. Most of the "energy" of each block is concentrated in the low frequency components which are at the beginning of the zig-zag order.